# Centrar "X" en animación de un botón hamburger

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy haciendo un botón con una animación: el típico botón *hamburger* que cambia a una X. El problema es que no logro hacer que luego de la animación, la X quede centrada.
Acá dejo el código:

```js
let toggle = document.getElementById("container-boton")

toggle.addEventListener("click", cositas)

function cositas(){
    if(toggle.classList.contains("active")){
        toggle.classList.remove("active")

    }else{
        toggle.classList.add("active")
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.container-boton{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
}

.container-boton .boton{
    background-color: black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 50cm;
}
.container-boton .boton::before,
.container-boton .boton::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 50cm;
    transition: 300ms;
}
.container-boton .boton::before{
    transform: translateY(16px);
}
.container-boton .boton::after{
    transform: translateY(-16px);
}
.container-boton.active .boton{
  transform: translateX(62px);
  background:transparent;
}

.container-boton.active .boton::before{
    transform: rotate(45deg)translate(43.4px, -43.4px);
}

.container-boton.active .boton::after{
    transform: rotate(-45deg)translate(43.4px, 43.4px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container-boton" class="container-boton">
        <div class="boton"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Me gustaría que quede centrado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo único que hice fue quitar las translaciones, puede que pusieras una por algún motivo luego no la necesitabas pero se quedó ahí, luego la trataste de compensar con otra translación.

He quitado ambas...

```js
let toggle = document.getElementById("container-boton")

toggle.addEventListener("click", cositas)

function cositas(){
    if(toggle.classList.contains("active")){
        toggle.classList.remove("active")

    }else{
        toggle.classList.add("active")
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.container-boton{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
}

.container-boton .boton{
    background-color: black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 50cm;
}
.container-boton .boton::before,
.container-boton .boton::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 50cm;
    transition: 300ms;
}
.container-boton .boton::before{
    transform: translateY(16px);
}
.container-boton .boton::after{
    transform: translateY(-16px);
}
.container-boton.active .boton{
  background:transparent;
}

.container-boton.active .boton::before{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.container-boton.active .boton::after{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container-boton" class="container-boton">
        <div class="boton"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Alfredo

Answer (score 2):

El problema lo tienes en una de tus reglas **CSS**, que está desplazando 62px a la derecha el icono, provocando que este se salga de su encuadre.

```
.container-boton.active .boton{
  transform: translateX(62px);
  background:transparent;
}
```

Como para tranformar las 3 líneas en una X ya lo estás teniendo que desplazar a la derecha, lo que te interesa es desplazarlo hacia la izquierda para que el icono no se salga. Sería cambiar el 62px por un -62px, que creo que es lo que se pretendía.

```js
let toggle = document.getElementById("container-boton")

toggle.addEventListener("click", cositas)

function cositas(){
    if(toggle.classList.contains("active")){
        toggle.classList.remove("active")

    }else{
        toggle.classList.add("active")
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.container-boton{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
}

.container-boton .boton{
    background-color: black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 50cm;
}
.container-boton .boton::before,
.container-boton .boton::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 50cm;
    transition: 300ms;
}
.container-boton .boton::before{
    transform: translateY(16px);
}
.container-boton .boton::after{
    transform: translateY(-16px);
}
.container-boton.active .boton{
  transform: translateX(-62px);
  background:transparent;
}

.container-boton.active .boton::before{
    transform: rotate(45deg)translate(43.4px, -43.4px);
}

.container-boton.active .boton::after{
    transform: rotate(-45deg)translate(43.4px, 43.4px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container-boton" class="container-boton">
        <div class="boton"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Guel